# Angular4 - Karma-Jessie; How to cover a response in ngOnInit?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, code-coverage

**Scenario**

[image]

Here is the code of the karma-test:

```
it('ngOnInit', inject([NuarKeySignatureService], (service: NuarKeySignatureService) => {
  const challenge = new SignatureResultPositionChallenge();
  challenge.challenge = ['1', '2', '3', '4'];
  service.setChallengeEvent(challenge);
  fixture.detectChanges();
  service.getChallengeEvent().subscribe(
    response => {
      expect(response.challenge).toEqual(challenge.challenge);
    }
  );
}));
```

**Problem**

I only covered the function `getChallengeEvent` and `getErrorEvent`. But I do not know how to cover the response of both functions. I think it could be a problem about synchronism. Do you know any solution for this?

Comment: This is probably what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44617366/angular-2-unit-test-function-called-from-ngoninit